# Do Bit vectors store memory locations?

Tags: hashtable, bitvector

Hello Computer Science World,

I am trying to answer this question..

**A bit vector is simply an array of bits (0s and 1s). A bit vector of length m takes
much less space than an array of m pointers. Describe how to use a bit vector
to represent a dynamic set of distinct elements with no satellite data. Dictionary
operations should run in O(1) time.**

My thinking is that a bit vector can be used to store the memory locations of the elements and since we are assuming that no two elements have the same key we can use hash function to store the memory location and access it in O(1) time.

Do Bit vectors store memory locations ?

If not can someone guide me to the promise land.

Thanks

Comment: Typically you wouldn't store memory addresses using a bitvector. What sort of elements are you planning on storing?

Comment: They can be any arbitrary elements @templatetypedef